# Displaying different Data on 7 segment

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, embedded, firmware

I am Designing a Digital Stabilizer ,where I have to Use a Multiplexed 7 segment Display to Show Input Voltage & Output Voltage ,I have successfully able to see input voltage but I am unable to figure out how to display I/P voltage for some time say 30 Secs and O/P voltage for 30 Secs.The display is using Interrupt for Handling Multiplexed 7 segment.

Additional data :
Micro controller :PIC16F72
Compiler : MikroC
Interrupt Source(Multiplexing) :Timer2

**How to Display two Different Voltages for a Certain Interval in a 7 segment Multiplexed display ?**

Comment: Is it a firmware problem only?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes , @Blup1980 .How to Display two Different Voltages for a Certain Interval in a 7 segment Multiplexed display ?

Comment: If that is the question it is pure programming, and it seems alike an easy task. What exactly is the problem, what have you tried so far? If your code is short, show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a (presumably timer) interrupt for the display multiplex timing, you can use that to time the 30s cycle. Consider this c-like pseudo-code. Upper case are constants from #defines.

Say this is a global variable (and therefore static):

```
volatile int my_timer; 

In your ISR: 

if (my_timer > 0) my_timer--; 

In your main routine

if (0==my_timer) 
   {
   // time-out - toggle the display source and reload the timer 
   display_source = (INPUT_VOLTAGE == display_source) ? OUTPUT_VOLTAGE:INPUT_VOLTAGE; 
   my_timer = 30 * MUX_FREQUENCY;  // MUX_FREQUENCY must be < 1092 Hz 
   }
// update display 

switch(display_source) 
  {
  INPUT_VOLTAGE: 
     // update display based on input voltage
     break;
  OUTPUT_VOLTAGE:
     // update display based on output voltage
     break; 
  default: 
     // update display with error message 
     break; 
   }
```